# Apps Script sends old feedback page, but new feedback inside email

Tags: google-apps-script

*I'm a beginner with Google app scirpts*

i want send a feedback-page to users feedback typed into html form.
the script considers my changes into the email anwser.
but the feedback pages is always rendered with old **form.html** not the new **antwortSeite.html**.

should i use inside the forms also **publish** as **webapp**?
i do this with the **Code.gs** file.

i tried this but could not find any updates.

```
fileNameAntwortSeite = 'antwortSeite.html'; // <?= email ?>
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(fileNameAntwortSeite);
template.email = 'huibuh@somebody.com'; 
antwortHtml = template.evaluate().getContent()
MailApp.sendEmail({to: kundenEmail, subject: 'test createTemplateFromFile'
                       , htmlBody: antwortHtml});      
return antwortHtml;
```

Comment: Where is the feedback page in the code you show? If the email has a URL that points to the script as a webapp, then you will need to deploy new versions in order for HTML updates to be reflected in the script's web app.

Comment: My guess is, if this is a web app you have to publish a new version for changes in the script editor to take effect.  Even though you may see the changes in code the version of the web app still contains the old form.html.  And if you run latest version from script editor that would use the latest code but still not update the web app.

Comment: i do: scriptEditor > publish > webApp  >... The URL has not changed. There was a link called "testing" i cklicked and got answer: "The script was completed, but the returned value is not a supported return type.". if i calls the page i got the old feedback formuler again.